# Septimus freezes during quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm in a quest where you should bring the blood to Septimus.

I've done it and he opened the "box". Inside is a big book, he stands near the book but doesn't do anything and I can't interact with him or the book.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what is supposed to happen:

> Septimus is about to pick up the book, but Hermaeus Mora decides that his usefulness has come to and end and he is disintegrated. You then pick up the [book](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Oghma_Infinium) yourself.

According to the UESP page for [Discerning the Transmundane](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Discerning_the_Transmundane), this is a known bug, and your best bet is to just kill Septimus.